# Comparing 2 column names and inserting mean values in Python

Tags: python, mean

My CSV file looks like this. The first row is column names which are wavelengths.

```
3000   3005   3010   3020   3025   3035
0.12   0.11   0.19   0.16   0.18   0.20
0.25   0.34   0.15   0.20   0.25   0.45
0.05   0.08   0.25   0.35   0.66   0.22
```

Like this I have a total of around 135 columns out of which 28 columns are missing. Columns are in increments of 5. So I want to compare the column names and insert the mean value of previous and next column data. For example, the columns `3015` is missing, so I want to compare that with the list of columns and insert the mean (e.g. `(0.19 + 0.16) / 2`) to the new column (`3015`).

Right now I'm just doing it manually like:

```
data["3015"] = None
data["3015"] = (data["3010"] + data["3020"]) / 2.
```

Is it possible to do this a more efficient way?

Comment: Note that you're doing `data[str(x)] = (data[str(x-5)] + data[str(x+5)]) / 2.`, and work from there. Also, you don't need to initialise to `None`.

Comment: What if two consecutive are missing, e.g. `3015` and `3020`? Or eight consecutive?

Comment: How have you loaded the csv? Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: @EdChum yeah i'm using pandas...

Comment: OK, are your columns str or ints? it should be obvious if you do `df.columns.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your columns are str or int the first line may need to change, but basically you can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) your df to generate the missing wavelengths and then call [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html#pandas.Series.interpolate) and pass `axis=1` to fill the missing values, this is equivalent to taking the mean of the measurement before and after:

```
In [149]:
new_df = df.reindex(columns=np.arange(3000, 3040, 5).astype(str))
new_df

Out[149]:
   3000  3005  3010  3015  3020  3025  3030  3035
0  0.12  0.11  0.19   NaN  0.16  0.18   NaN  0.20
1  0.25  0.34  0.15   NaN  0.20  0.25   NaN  0.45
2  0.05  0.08  0.25   NaN  0.35  0.66   NaN  0.22

In [158]:
new_df.interpolate(axis=1)

Out[158]:
   3000  3005  3010   3015  3020  3025  3030  3035
0  0.12  0.11  0.19  0.175  0.16  0.18  0.19  0.20
1  0.25  0.34  0.15  0.175  0.20  0.25  0.35  0.45
2  0.05  0.08  0.25  0.300  0.35  0.66  0.44  0.22
```

So if your columns are str like below:

```
In [146]:    
df.columns.tolist()

Out[146]:
['3000', '3005', '3010', '3020', '3025', '3035']
```

then you need to cast the result of `np.arange` as I've shown if there are ints then you don't need to cast so this will do:

```
new_df = df.reindex(columns=np.arange(3000, 3040, 5))
```